# Can't store values into array MATLAB

Tags: arrays, matlab

I have a 1x280 structure in Matlab. In order for me to use the values, I changed it to `struct2cell` array.

An example of how one of the structures among the 280 looks is below :

```
Field       Value               Min       Max

point1      [29,469]            29        469
point2      [42,469]            42        469
-------------------------------------------
```

After changing to a cell array using the below code:

```
showlines = struct(lines);
cellData = struct2cell(showlines);


cellData{1,1}(1) 
    = 29
```

However, if I use this :

```
cellData{1,1:280}(1);
```

There is an error

```
Error:: bad cell reference operation
```

I would need to keep all the `x` values of `point1` in each of the 280 structures into an array so as to find out the maximum `X` value of `point1` in them. Any idea how to do it?

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Although not a direct answer to your question, you might be interested to know that

```
%# some example data
S(1).point1 = [29 469];
S(1).point2 = [42 469];

S(2).point1 = [30 470];
S(2).point2 = [43 470];

...

S(280).point1 = [130 870];
S(280).point2 = [243 970];

%# transform to regular array
pt1 = reshape([S.point1],[],2).';
pt2 = reshape([S.point2],[],2).';
```

will result in

```
pt1 = [29   469       pt2 = [42   469
       30   470              43   470
       ...                   ... 
       130  870];            243  970];
```

which enables you to do things like

```
>> pt1(:, 2)
ans = 
    469
    470
    ..
    870

>> min(pt1(:,1))
ans = 
    29
```

Does that solve your problem?

To any passers by: what is the notation `[S.field]` for non-scalar `structs` called? Does it even have a name? Questions involving this technique frequently pop-up, and it would help if I knew what it's called so I can post a link to the manual page in the answer...

Comment: Yes, that solves my problem if I have only S(1) to S(3) or so. However in my case there is 280 'S' due to my structure having 280 of that. How do I go about filling those S(3) to S(280) point1 and point 2 automatticaly? Thanks

Comment: @Melvyn my answer just gives an example. The same line (i.e., `[S.point1]`) will work perfectly fine even when `S` contains a billion values. Did you try the above on your own structure?

Comment: sorry, so do I change "S" into my own cell array name? I.E after struct2cell, i renamed the cell array as "cellData". This array has 280 point1 and point2. So do I write [cellData.point1]?

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis You might have some memory problems with a billion values. :)

Comment: @Doresoom *conceptually speaking*, of course :) BTW, 1e9 values is about 8GB == no problem at all on my machine :p

Comment: @Melvyn no, you should skip `struct2cell` alltogether; just do `showlines = struct(lines);  pt1 = reshape([showlines.point1], [],2).'; ` etc.